# How to test prototypal inheritance from util.inherits()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I test that a class inherits another when I use util.inherits to make the inheritance happen?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly can't you just check that an instance of the subclass is an `instanceof` the superclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
var util = require("util"),
    assert = require("assert");

function Parent() {}
function Child() {}

util.inherits(Child, Parent);

var child = new Child();
assert(child instanceof Parent); // Test that `child` inherits from `Parent`
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. I was doing almost the same thing, but instead of checking an Instance of the subclass, I was directly checking the subclass with `instanceof`...

Comment: You're welcome. Easy mistake to make, although the clue is in the name... `instanceof` is used to check if an *instance* inherits from the constructor in question!